# conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'another value' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a `select` statement and when the `type_id` in one table is 1, that is a string, so I need to select the `value_string` from another table, but when `type_id` is 2, that is an int, so I need to select `value_int`.

Here is my query

```sql
select
    ps.link_id, ps.name, sla.store_nbr,
    case
        when ps.type_id = 1 then psd.value_string
        when ps.type_id = 2 then psd.value_int
        when ps.type_id = 6 then psd.value_any
    end
from
    links.project_schema ps
    join links.links l on l.id = ps.link_id
    join links.store_link_assignment sla on sla.links_id = link_id
    join links.project_schema_details psd on psd.project_schema_id = ps.id
where ps.link_id = 100551
```

I am getting the above error because the type is a 1 so `psd.value_string` should be what is selected but if it isn't I would want the query to use value_int for this particular select statement I am not sure how do do the if(ps.type_id ==1) then select psd.valuestring if it is 2 then select psd.value_int column.

Comment: Well, `'another value'` isn't an `int`. The error is telling you the problem here. I *suspect* you're comparing a `varchar` to an `int` somewhere, and `int` has a higher data type precedence that `varchar`, so it'll implicitly  converted

Comment: A column has one fixed type. You cannot dynamically choose the type of a column based on the data. Your `case` expression has the type that has higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) among the columns `value_string`, `value_int` and `value_any`. If `value_any` is `sql_variant`, then it's `sql_variant`, and if it's `varchar`, then it's `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One little cheat is to use `concat()` to return string values for the variable data types.

```
select
    ps.link_id, ps.name, sla.store_nbr,
    case
        when ps.type_id = 1 then concat('',psd.value_string)
        when ps.type_id = 2 then concat('',psd.value_int)
        when ps.type_id = 6 then concat('',psd.value_any)
    end
from
    links.project_schema ps
    join links.links l on l.id = ps.link_id
    join links.store_link_assignment sla on sla.links_id = link_id
    join links.project_schema_details psd on psd.project_schema_id = ps.id
where ps.link_id = 100551
```

Comment: this worked for me thanks John but I am wondering what would happen if I got a different value type so lets say ps.type_id is 2 then it would be an int and concating this would make this situation fail.

Comment: @josh Always happy to help.   concat('',somevalue)  will return a string regardless of type.  Also if values are NULL except for ONE column you could eliminate the CASE and simply     concat('',value_string,value_int,value_any)

Comment: yes the concat is exactly what I need I do not need the case thank you you are right only one value is not null from that statement.